# Importing non-unique terms with Feeds Importer

Tags: taxonomy-terms, feeds

I'm trying to import a large chunk of data to our site using Feeds Importer. However, I've come to a small problem when trying to map a piece of our data to a collection of taxonomy terms.

The problem is as follows:

We have a vocabulary called Categories with two levels. Every parent term has a list of child terms.
In some of our terms, both the parent and the child have the same name, e.g.:

parent; child
Cozinhas; Cozinhas

This is absolutely necessary as we need both the main category and the sub category to be listed and presented in this fashion.

With Feeds Importer we simply import all the main (parent) categories once and the every sub (child) categories related to it (e.g.: "Casas de Banho" -> "Banheiras"). However, in this case, it simply maps the term to the parent and lists it twice. We are using Hierarchical Select to save the terms, so we use Tamper to explode the terms we've imported and send it to the correct field.

I've tried importing the alias of the sub-category term ("Cozinhas-0") and the unique ID to map it correctly but it simply doesn't work that way, it seems it has to be the term name.

Is there any way to map this correctly?

tl;dr:

We need to import several values, with Feeds Importer, into a single Hierarchical Select field and we need them to be unique, in order to map same-name taxonomy terms to their correct ID. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, there is a way to map by term ID on the mapping settings of the Feeds Importer.

[image]

Problem solved!

Comment: How would you achieve this on the new Feeds 3? I have a terms already on Drupal and looking to import and I currently do not have TermIDs.